# How to use "observe_field" in JQuery model dialog box on rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events

I'm developing project on rails 2.3.8 and I need to use observe_field in model dialog box but it didn't work for me. Is it possible to use "observe_field" on model dialog box? Please can some one explain me how to use this on model dialog box ?
This how I use observe filed

```
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
<%= link_to_remote 'Show calendar', :url => {:controller => 'calendar', :action => 'dynamicTrainer'} %>

<%= observe_field 'event',
:url => {:controller => 'calendar', :action=> 'dynamicTr'},
:with => "'mypara=' + escape(value)" %>
```

This is dynamicTr method in calendar controller.

```
def dynamicTr
 if (defined? (params[:trainer_id]))
     session[:my123] = 'defined'
 else
     session[:my123] = 'not'
 end
end



 def dynamicTrainer




session[:mySerach]=params[:mypara]
@month = (params[:month] || (Time.zone || Time).now.month).to_i
@year = (params[:year] || (Time.zone || Time).now.year).to_i
@shown_month = Date.civil(@year, @month)
@trainers=Trainer.all 
@first_day_of_week = 1

    if session[:mySerach].nil?
        if (defined? (params[:mypara]))
            session[:mySerach]=(params[:mypara])

            #@@id=(params[:event][:trainer_id])
            @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week, :conditions=>["trainer_id = ?",session[:mySerach]])          
        else
            @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week)              
        end
    else
        @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week, :conditions=>["trainer_id = ?",session[:mySerach]])          
    end     
end
```

And this is my dynamicTrainer.js.rjs file

```
page.replace_html 'show_cal', :partial => 'dynamicTr'

page<< "$j ('#show_cal_dialog').dialog({
    title: 'calendar',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
   height: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $j ('#show_cal_dialog').dialog('destroy') }

});"
```

This is dynamicTr partial code

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "event_calendar" %>
<%= event_calendar%>
<%= session[:my123]%>
```

problem is it shows the calendar but it doesn't print the session values. Can't I use observe_field on model dialog box ? Please can someone explain me the problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a problem in your observe field.

use the id of collection_select field in observe field as 'event_trainer_id'

```
<%= observe_field 'event_trainer_id,
:url => {:controller => 'calendar', :action=> 'dynamicTr'},
:with => "'mypara=' + escape(value)" %>
```